# Descobrindo o SQL de um ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, resultset

Tenho Um objeto java ResultSet que não sei o SQL/parametros que gerou ele.
Gostaria de saber como faço pra pegar o SQL usado pra criar-lo?
teria algo do tipo :

```
  rs.getStm.getSql
```

?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito confusa, você quer algo do como isso : `timeStamp = rs.getTimestamp("data");` ? ou quer saber qual tabela gerou o resultado ?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino creio que ele quer saber qual foi a `SQL` que deu origem ao seu `ResultSet`

Comment: isso mesmo @Dener,  quero o SQL do ResultSet

Answer (score 2):

Você deve pegar o SQL de java.sql.PreparedStatement:

```
System.out.println(ps);
```

Basta chamar o toString de PrepareStatement.

Comment: Isso funciona em contextos em que não é usado o driver *JDBC* do MySQL?

Comment: Qual o seu driver? Testei agora no mysql e sei que funciona no postgre também.

Comment: =/ infelizmente no jaybird não funciona, acho que isso seja uma implementação dependendo do driver e da inteligência do desenvolvedor que criou o driver

Comment: Nesse eu não testei.

Mas tente fazer um debug (com eclipse, netbeans, etc.). Talvez no debug você ache alguma propriedade que está guardando a informação que precisa (o sql, no caso).

Comment: ja tentei deburar pra ver se eu achava alguma coisa, mas não achei nada

Answer (score 2):

Estou escrevendo isso me baseando neste [javadoc](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.7/docs/).

Pelo javadoc, a classe `FirebirdResultSet` herda do `ResultSet` da biblioteca `java.sql`.

A classe `ResultSet` tem o método `getStatement()` que retorna um objeto `Statement`; daí você pode seguir a resposta do usuário [@Afonso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/25756/afonso), e chamar o método `toString` da classe `Statement`.

Comment: no caso do firebird o FirebirdStatement (retornado pelo getStatement) não está implementado o toString retornando aqueles hachs/endereço de memoria( eu nunca soube o que eh aquilo) marotos de quando uma classe não implementa o toString deixando o padrão

Comment: Então a minha sugestão é entrar em modo debug e procurar onde está a query no FBStatement, e então imprimir a query.

Answer (score 0):

Só complementando o senhor Afonso. Com Postgre funciona também. Só utilizar o método toString() com o PreparedStatement.

```
preparedStatement = conection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM usuario");
System.out.println(preparedStatement.toString());
```

Console:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario
```

Com Statement comum não funciona pois o sql é inserido diretamente com o método executeQuery.